# magento 2 category delete function programmatically

Tags: magento2.3.1

I would like to **delete categories** and **sub categories** pro-grammatically in magneto 2.

> Please suggest me proper code for it.

Comment: Category and subcategory delete any one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test both option (an empty category tree or a already created category tree), I added a **deleteAllCategories** function.

> This function looks like this:

```
<?php
...
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

/**
 * Class CategoryDeletion
 * @package Project\Catalog
 */
class CategoryDeletion
{
    /** @var Registry $registry */
    private $registry;


    /** @var CategoryFactory $categoryFactory */
    protected $categoryFactory

    /**
     * Category Deletion constructor.
     * @param CategoryFactory      $categoryFactory      Category Factory
     * @param Registry             $registry             Magento Registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategoryFactory             $categoryFactory,
        Registry                    $registry
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory      = $categoryFactory;
        $this->registry             = $registry;
    }


    /**
     * Remove categories tree
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function removeCategories()
    {
        $categories = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getCollection();

        $this->registry->register("isSecureArea", true);
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            if($category->getId() > 2) {
                $category->delete();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I’m using a category factory to get a collection of all available categories. In a foreach loop I call

> $category->delete()

for each single category. The only thing to mention is, that is not a good idea to delete category root (has id 2). As I showed in my delete all products **programmatically** article, it is only possible to delete a category if you **declare a secure area**

The code above only works if you have **injected registry** and *get object manager singleton.* This code shows how this can be done:

```
class MyClass{

protected $_objectManager;
protected $_registry;
...
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    }
```

**May this will helps you!**

Comment: sir now i have two category men and watch men is a main category and watch is sub category.men delete time automatically delete watch is it possible

Comment: yes, you have to select specific category for delete like above we select all category u have to select specific category for this, maybe it is subcategory or main category! approve, if it will help you! Thanks:)

Comment: sir i want to delete 001 category and sub category can you rearrange this code

Comment: i have updated above code for specific category, like id of the categoty is 2, that we want to delete!

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: sir one more question.how to update my sub category to another category.

Comment: eg: i have two category Men and Kids.Men have another sub category watch and kids have another sub category toys.how to update watch to kids category.can you help me

Comment: you have to post a question for it, i will surely helps you!

Comment: Ok sir i am waiting for you

Comment: Yes sure u have to just post a new question for it, i will answer the question there, not here!

Comment: Sir my question is  i have two category Men and Kids.Men have another sub category watch and kids have another sub category toys.how to update watch to kids category

Comment: i am patiently waiting for this

Comment: ok, i will let you know!

Comment: My client added random categories as parent they were around 200+. I created this snippet to delete them. You may find it helpful.

<?php $OM =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$categoryCollection = $OM->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');?>
<?php

$registry = $OM->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register("isSecureArea", true);
$cats = $categoryCollection->create();
$cats = $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    if ($cat->getId() > 3) {
        $cat->delete();
    }
}
?>